# How to put screenshots in one pdf file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a setup where I run the test, and the screenshot is captured. If I run *100s* of tests, I get *100s* of `png` files in the screenshot folder. Is this possible to save all screenshots in one file as a `pdf`, rather than individual file.
Thanks!

Comment: may be this could help -- [pdf images](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/image.html)

Comment: Which selenium language bindings are you using?

Comment: @VivekSingh, Thanks for suggesting an awesome API. It solved the purpose.

Comment: @alecxe I am using Java